# Use other font in restricted area won't compile

Tags: fonts, luatex, moderncv

I'm trying to change the font of only one character in the document, but it won't compile with lualatex, what am I missing?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\moderncvicons{awesome}

\newfontfamily\myfont[]{Arial}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\email{someName{\myfont @}me.com}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in the fact that `\email{x}` eventually does

```
\href{mailto:x}{x}
```

and `\myfont` in the first argument to `\href` is wrong. You can work around this with some trick, but the link will be invalid.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\moderncvicons{awesome}

\newfontfamily\myfont[]{Arial}
\protected\def\myat{{\myfont @}}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\email{someName\myat me.com}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a better work around that produces a valid hyperlink. Now `\email` has an optional argument for specifying formatting instructions, so `\maketitle` will do

```
\href{mailto:someName@me.com}{someName{\myfont @}me.com}
```

which is legal.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\moderncvicons{awesome}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}
  {\emaillink{\@email}}
  {\expandafter\emaillink\@email}
  {}{}
\renewcommand{\email}{\@dblarg\fry@fix@email}
\def\fry@fix@email[#1]#2{\def\@email{[#1]{#2}}}
\makeatother

\newfontfamily\myfont[]{Arial}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\email[someName{\myfont @}me.com]{someName@me.com}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg: can't we simply say: `\renewcommand*{\email}{someName{\myfont @}me.com}` and, later on,
`\href{mailto:someName@me.com}{\email}` ...so we'll have both the new @ and a correct hyperlink?

Comment: @Fry Now you can also produce a valid link.

Comment: @NilsL Yes, but some surgery on the commands of `moderncv` are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you simply forgot to load `fontspec`, which is the package that provides the `\newfontfamily` command:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\myfont[]{Arial}

\begin{document}
someName{\myfont @}me.com
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd say this is not the case, because the error is *not* caused by `\newfontfamily`.

Comment: and it will still not compile, when adding \usepackage{fontspec} to my MWE. (i want to use moderncv not scrartcl)

Comment: it seems that `moderncv` implicitly loads `fontspec`, which I find odd. But egreg is right of course: in that case, a missing `\usepackage{fontspec}` can't be the cause of the problem.

Comment: No, it's `\moderncvicons{awesome}` that does it.